# Capture Return Value of python script invoked from C#

Tags: c#, python

I am trying to capture return (list) from python script below using C#. Stream reader gives me a null as a response. However, when I print the result I get the information in stream reader but  when I use return(list) it does not.I have tried a lot of ways. Links and any info is appreciated. 
Python:

```
def main1():

    data1 =send_initdata("i", sock)

    list.append (send_data("a", sock,"1"))
    list.append (send_data("b", sock,"2"))

    #print (list)
    return (list)


if __name__ == '__main__':sys.exit(main1())
```

C#:

```
    void run_cmd()
    {


        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = @"C:\Python27\python.exe";
        start.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", "Function.Py", "");
        start.UseShellExecute = false;
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        start.CreateNoWindow = true;


        using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                var result = reader.ReadLine();

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

The return from a command-line process is always an integer, and is intended to indicate the presence or absence of errors during execution.  You can't return a list as you're trying to do here.

Having the script print the list contents to STDOUT (as your commented `print` statement does), and then read that as your C# code does is the correct way to go.  Alternately the script could write the list to a file and then your C# code read that file.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information Andrew! Now in C# if I use scope = engine.ExecuteFile( fileName);  How can I use scope to run python file? Python file which has:if __name__ == '__main__':sys.exit(main1()) Appreciate your help!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about the workings of Python, just command-line processes in general.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, By any chance you have any idea how can I capture single python function print command? var ipy = Python.CreateRuntime(options);
dynamic Python_File = ipy.UseFile("Function.Py");

Python_File.main1();// how can I capture this output?

Comment: I don't know what `Python.CreateRuntime` is.  Is that Iron Python?  It's possible that the API just sends the output of the python script directly to the STDOUT of your C# process.